# Which rails model do I put a multiple table query in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables called

```
Product (prodID: integer, prodName: string, userID: FK)
```

and

```
User(userID:integer,userName:string).
```

The user can have many products. I want to write a query that gets me all the products for userID=10. I don't however understand which model I should put this in- the user or the product model or does it not matter? Presumably the output of the model will be fed to the controller it relies on so I should put it in the model that relates to the view I want to show it in? Is this correct?

Comment: In User model you can have `has_many :products` and in Product model have it like `belongs_to :user`. Then you'll be able to use `User.find(10).products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@products = User.of_products(params[:id])
```

If you don't want to use @user in your action then you can avoid calculating @user.

In user.rb:

```
has_many :products

def self.of_products(user_id)
  User.includes(:products).where(id: user_id) 
end
```

This will give you all products of @user

Comment: This is fine for simple queries but what about for more complex ones? Should they be put in the model?

Comment: Ok so how is this written in the model ( does it matter if it goes in the user or product model) and then how does the controller refer to it?

Comment: It should go to users model

Comment: Ok so what should I write in the user model and how does the controller refer to it?

Comment: This is a bit like getting blood from a stone. What do I write in the model and how do I pass this to the controller?

Comment: Hello user123. Please see my comments for what I want to do. I want to do it in the model and pass it to the controller

Comment: check my updated code. In model with the query I have written, you can write your own query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79481/discussion-between-user123-and-sebastian-zeki).

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use association method, no need of writing model method for fetching user's products.

```
In user.rb:
has_many :products

In product.rb
belongs_to :user

and from controller
User.where('id = ?', params[:id]).first.try(:products)
```

So, above query will fetch products if user with given id is found.

Comment: I like this. My only reservation is with bigger queries which I thought had to run in the model which is why I'm really looking for a model centric answer